# What's the difference between Send-Q and S-BCNT in FreeBSD netstat -anx?

Tags: freebsd, tcp, netstat

What's the exact meaning of Send Buffer byte count in the extended netstat statistics, and why is it always bigger than Send-Q?

In other words, what's counted against the S-BCNT that's not counted against the Send-Q?

Is S-BCNT a better number to use to figure the cost to the system of a particular connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find definition along with comments at `sys/sys/sockbuf.h`:

```
    u_int   sb_cc;      /* (c/d) actual chars in buffer */
    u_int   sb_mbcnt;   /* (c/d) chars of mbufs used */
```

BSDs are using structures called `mbuf`/`mbuf_cluster` for network data. They used everywhere from driver code to socket layer. Even if packet had 1 byte of payload it will consume 256 (`mbuf`) bytes in mbuf. If packet size (with all frame/packet headers) >= 256 it will consume 256 (`mbuf`) + 2048 (`mbuf_cluster`) bytes. Hence the difference between `sb_cc` and `sb_mbcnt`.

To answer your question: `S-BCNT` is more correct value to use.

**PS**. For more information consult to [TCP/IP Illustrated Volume 2 - W. Richard Stevens and Garry R. Wright](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0026OR0JM), Chapter 16 - Socket I/O, Section 16.3 - Socket Buffers, p.476